# About Math.floor(Double.MIN_VALUE)

Tags: java

why is Math.floor(Double.MIN_VALUE) == 0 ?
can any one send me the java algorithme of Floor function or at least explain this result please?

Comment: All due respect, but the briefest glance at the documentation for [`Double.MIN_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MIN_VALUE) and (if you need it at that point) [`Math.floor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor(double)) would have answered this for you.

Comment: Double.MIN_VALUE is very close to 0, so when you round it down you get 0.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`Double.MIN_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MIN_VALUE) doesn't mean what you think it means. It means "the smallest positive `double` value" - so naturally when you take the "floor" of it (largest integer less than or equal to the value), you'll get 0. Documentation:

> A constant holding the smallest positive nonzero value of type double, 2<sup>-1074</sup>. It is equal to the hexadecimal floating-point literal 0x0.0000000000001P-1022 and also equal to Double.longBitsToDouble(0x1L).

I agree that the name is confusing, but it's always worth checking the documentation as soon as you see confusing behaviour.

If you want to get the "lowest" finite `double`, just use `-double.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: ...agreed. Just "hover" your mouse over MIN_VALUE and its deepest secrets will be revealed to you. :-)